# jQuery: show() keeps adding display:block

Tags: jquery

I'm having a little issue right now that has turned into a festering wound.

I've recreated Google Business Hours for setting which hours during the week that a company is open, or whether they are closed on that day. Now, if they are closed, the user can select a checkbox and the times DIV hides. Right now I'm using `.show()` and `.hide()`

Now, let's say that a user closes the first day and decides to "apply all" to the rest of the days of the week. I loop through and close the remaining 6 days. However, if a user has modified a day in the middle of the week, the `.show()` or `.hide()` functions automatically add `"display: block"` and this messes up the loop.

Why is jQuery adding this styling when it was never there originally, and is there a clean way of removing it within a loop before I apply the `.show()` or `.hide()`?

Comment: I don't understand how it breaks the loop. jQuery uses `display:none` and `display:block` to hide and show elements if there is no preset CSS proprety for how they are originally shown. ------ Some sample code might help clarify things.

Comment: It doesn't break the loop in the traditional sense. The loop is simply meant to either add or remove a "hidden" class. .show() and .hide() manually add a display property and this effectively messes with the loop. Instead of using .show, I'm just going to manually add/remove the class. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's addClass() and removeClass() if you're not happy with the effect of show() and hide(), and attach a class to change the visibility, for example.

Comment: Except then he loses animation and has to recreate those if he's using that effect.

Comment: No animation needed in this case. The .show() and .hide() effects automatically take the liberty to inject a display... I don't want that. So I've decided to ignore it and just manually add or remove a "hidden" class.

Comment: While this is the best in many cases, I ended up with doing.
$(this).css("display", ""); To get rid of the injected display:block.

Answer (score 6):

On an element that you haven't defined the display, after unhidding it, JQUERY will add display block to the element.

You can remove it afterwards.

```
$("#myrow").show().removeAttr( 'style' )
```

This includes all dynamic styling so please watch out if you depend on this.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/show/

> The matched elements will be revealed
>   immediately, with no animation. This
>   is roughly equivalent to calling
>   `.css('display', 'block')`, except that
>   the display property is restored to
>   whatever it was initially. If an
>   element has a display value of inline,
>   then is hidden and shown, it will once
>   again be displayed inline.

Do you have an original css display property set?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery uses 'display:none' to hide().I use this and show() quite frequently but I haven't had any problem yet probably because display:block hasn't hurt my formatting.

Here's a quick remedy for your situation

```
$("#mydiv").show().css("display","inline")
```

Use the div setting you want instead of inline (while inline will probably work for you considering block isn't.

Comment: You should reverse those so that the CSS is already set before .show() runs and then you don't have to set it again. Or better, define the CSS on #mydiv to have display:inline to begin with before the jQuery gets a chance to work

Comment: I tried this method. Was the first thing I did... it doesn't quite act that way. But, in theory, if I decide to use .show again in the future, I will definitely define which display I want from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cyril Gupta's and Jimmy Kane's answers, use this on a hidden div:

```
$("#hiddenDiv").css("display","");
```

This simply clears the "none" from display, your stylesheet should take over from there.